# Mahout Item Recommender score for every combination of user and item

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

We're looking to create a recommender using Mahout that will generate a recommendation score for every combination of user and item based on a users rating of items.

The number of items is fairly small so we believe the amount of data should be manageable.

We're currently using the itembasedrecommender and tried increasing the number of numRecommendations config, but we couldn't get it to provide a recommendation for each user and item.

Do you have any recommendation on either how we could configure this or another algorithm or piece of software that could help us achieve this?